# Extract differences from logs

Tags: linux, extract, comm

Sorry if it's a simple shell programming question but I couldn't find a way to do exactly what I wanted.

I have 2 logs.

`log1`

```
Cust   Subsys    StartDate   EndDate        col1      col2      col3
1001   10000      20150501    20150731      6.1700    0.0000   0.0000   -- this line is identical in both logs 
1001   12000      20150401    20150630      0.0000    0.0000   0.0000   -- this line is missing from log2
1003   13000      20150310    20150630      2.4800    0.0000   0.0000   -- the value in log1.col1 is different from the one in log2.col1
```

And `log2`

```
Cust   Subsys    StartDate    EndDate        col1      col2      col3
1001   10000      20150501    20150731      6.1700    0.0000   0.0000   -- this line is identical in both logs 
1003   13000      20150310    20150630      9.1800    0.0000   0.0000   -- the value in log1.col1 is different from the one in log2.col1
7000   7777       20150406    20150413      4.3300    0.0000   0.0000   -- this line is missing from log1
```

I would like to generate 3 reports out of these logs:

1. Lines found in `log1` but not in `log2`
2. Lines found in `log2` but not in `log1`
3. Lines that are identical in the first 4 columns of `log1` and `log2` but have different values on columns : `col1`,`col2` or `col3`.

I sorted both logs on all the columns:

```
cat log1 |sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2r -k3,3 -k4,4 -k5,5 -k6,6 -k7,7 > log1.sorted
cat log2 |sort -n -k1,1 -k2,2r -k3,3 -k4,4 -k5,5 -k6,6 -k7,7 > log2.sorted
```

Then I tried to use comm to generated the first 2 reports:

```
comm -13  log1.sorted  log2.sorted  > unique2.log
comm -23  log1.sorted  log2.sorted  > unique1.log
```

And I noticed that there are lines in `unique1.log` that can be found in `log1` and `log2` . (my logs have over 20.000 lines in each) Is `comm` not used for extracting lines that are not in one of the logs? Does it only work if line numbers are the same? ( the line found in  `unique1.log` is number `188` in `log1` and `207` in `log2`)

How could I extract data for the 3rd report where I only want to show the lines that have different values in `col1` `col2` or `col3`?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it that way

```
comm -23 sort_file1 sort_file2 unique_in_file1
comm -13 sort_file1 sort_file2 unique_in_file2
comm -12 sort_file1 sort_file2 common_entries
```

If this doesnt work for you try to look at tge diff command.

Comment: Using the above command `comm -23 <(sort log1)<(sort log2)>unique_in_file1.log` did not work.I received the following error `ksh: 0403-057 Syntax error: `(' is not expected.`